# Facebook share - Missing texts

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

## Original Problem

*I did some more research, see the info on the bottom of the post. Thanks!*

I've an Android app, with Facebook sharing option. I did the sharing part of the app mostly from the tutorial on Fb. Dev. site, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Here's the actual code:

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        String name = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.shareFacebook_title), user.getName(), petName);
        String caption = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.shareFacebook_caption));
        String description = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.shareFacebook_description), user.getName(), petName, shelterName);
        postParams.putString("name", name);
        postParams.putString("caption", caption);
        postParams.putString("description", description);
        postParams.putString("link", getResources().getString(R.string.shareFacebook_url));
        postParams.putString("picture", petPicUrl);

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
                HttpMethod.POST);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

My problem is, the shared link does not have all the texts, I put into the `bundle`. See the pic:

[image: Facebook share]

When I run the debugger, and debug into the app, all of the `postParams` runs fine, and the `Bundle` have all the texts, but the share looks the same (and does not have all of the texts).
The `Bundle` throws some unexpected `ClassNotFoundExceptions`, but I think it's an error in the IDE, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348835/classnotfoundexception-in-android-util-arraymap-inside-intent).

[image: Debugging in the IDE]

The missing texts are not the same from all phone. From some phones, the picture missis too, but I'm sure, that the URL is right.

I know, that this worked 2-3 weeks ago, and nobody touched this code until today.

Can you help me, what's causing the problem?
Thanks!

## Edit

I've tried the Facebook's [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), to send the same query, and I've got the same result (missing texts, etc).

Here's the query:

[image: The same query from the Graph API Explorer]

Is it possible, that the Graph API is wrong/broken? Is it changed in the past few weeks? The [status page](https://developers.facebook.com/status/) says, that the API is healthy.

## Edit#2

Ok, so if I want to share any link, thoose attributes works. But if I want to share a link to Google Play, the attributes stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably that caused my problem, that the Google Play Store defines the oauth tags in the code, so FB parses that tags instead of my content.

The best solution, I found, was to link to a blank site, where from I redirect my users with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this use Facebook dialoug

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did not want to show any dialog, I'd like to share the post without any user-interaction.

Comment: used this code shair intent this will work with facebook native app

Comment: I do not want to rely on the installed Facebook app. My solution has to work on a phone without installed Facebook app. My solution has to work without any user interaction (do not want to show the share dialog!). I want to use the Graph API itself.